# Can I get a class or method's description programmatically?

Tags: ruby

If a class or a method has rdoc comment, how can I retrieve the doc with the Class object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [method_source gem](https://github.com/banister/method_source). 
It is used in pry.

For example this code from github:

```
Set.instance_method(:merge).comment.display
```

shows comment from Set#merge.

On other hand, if you have any command you can execute it and get return string from it via adding backtick before and after command or using `%x` syntax:

```
%x{ri Object.new}
`ri Object.new`
```